# can't pass the post value to curl

Tags: php, curl, watson-conversation, watson

This is my code.In this case, it will not take the post value (`$con`) to input text  in `$cmd`

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['conversation']))
  {
  $con=$_POST['conversation'];
  echo $con;
  $cmd='curl -X POST -u "username":"password" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"input\": {\"text\":\"$con\"]}}""https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/a9379972-d820-4cdf-b1cb-ad0af898a534/message?version=2016-07-11"';
  exec($cmd,$result);
 //$response = json_decode($result);
 print_r($result);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you aware that PHP has built-in commands for working with cURL?

Comment: Better to use php [curl extension](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

Comment: 1. There's no space between your data hash argument and the URL which causes the URL to be part of your POST data, but doesn't post to a URL
2. There's an errant `]` in your POST data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use PHP's [built-in curl commands](http://php.net/curl):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['conversation'])) {
    $data = array("input"=>array("text"=>$_POST["conversation"]));
    $url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/a9379972-d820-4cdf-b1cb-ad0af898a534/message?version=2016-07-11";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "username:password",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type:application/json"),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r(json_decode($response));
}
?>
```

Comment: can I use Ajax to call Curl here because it loads the page every time when I'm using the textbox?@miken32

Answer (score 1):

You're taking a raw `POST` value and passing it as a command line argument. This is a terrible idea. It opens you up wide to remote execution attacks. Someone could easily post a conversation value of "; sudo rm -rf /". Bad news. Not escaping the input will almost certainly break the JSON hash you are trying to send.

Next, you are missing a space between your POST data and the URL, so curl won't even see a URL.

If you need to execute the command line version of curl, use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on your values.

Ideally, use the PHP curl library. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
Then you can programmatically use curl and you don't have to worry about spawning a `curl` process or how args are escaped.

Comment: While entirely true, this doesn't attempt to answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: The breakage of the `curl` command is likely related to not escaping the input.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of the use of ' and ". You had enclosed `$con` in single quotes so it was not getting parsed :

```
$bob = 'hello';
$a = '$bob';
$b = "$bob";

$a : $bob
$b : hello
```